# Free Map matching benchmark data

Tags: data, map-matching, benchmark

I have my own map matching algorithm and I want to compare it's accuracy to some other algorithms. Is there a free trace dataset that has a confirmed match for each trace (ground truth), so I can perform the comparison? Even more, I would be interested in a whole benchmark/test suite for this purpose.

Comment: If you are seeking open data then the place to ask will be the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Would be interested to know if such a thing exists for evaluating our own system as well. Maybe some of the traces of openstreetmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found trace dataset suitable for the benchmarking, containing 100 traces from different parts of the world. It is described in the article called *Dataset for testing and training of map-matching algorithms by Kubicka et al.* (available on [IEEE](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7225829)).

The dataset itself is stored on [zenodo.org](https://zenodo.org/record/57731#.XUsQQ-hLiUk) as an open-access dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This paper by Newsom and Krumm on map-matching includes a test dataset that you can use to evaluate other algorithms. It's called "[Hidden Markov Map Matching Through Noise and Sparseness](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/hidden-markov-map-matching-noise-sparseness/)."

Comment: I know this article, but I don't think that one trace is enough for benchmarking.